# How to favour exact search matches in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch. I played around a bit and was a bit irritated that, when searching for a search phrase, documents containing a slightly different spelling get the same score as documents containing the exact word.

This is my search query (in PHP):

```
$params = [
'index' => 'twitter',
'type'  => 'tweet',
'body'  => [
    'query' => [
    'match' => [
            'message' => [
                'query' => 'triing',
                'type' => 'phrase',
                'fuzziness' => '2'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
];
```

And this is the result:

First the almost fitting:

```
[_index] => twitter
[_type] => tweet
[_id] => 2
[_score] => 0.15342642
[_source] => Array
    (
        [user] => kimchy
        [postDate] => 2016-06-01T11:54:10.285Z
        [message] => trying out Elasticsearch
    )
```

Second the exact fitting:

```
[_index] => twitter
[_type] => tweet
[_id] => 3
[_score] => 0.15342641
[_source] => Array
    (
        [user] => kimchy
        [postDate] => 2016-06-01T17:56:46.957Z
        [message] => triing out Elasticsearch
    )
```

1. Why are they scored the same? (actually the exact is even slightly less!!!)
2. How can I favor the exact over the almost exact? How do I favor an almost exact over a slightly less exact? (depending on a "distance")

Comment: This reference should be helpful in explaining the scores: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-scoring.html

Comment: But in a real life search I want to have documents containing the exact word on top and not exact matches below. How do I do that with Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default for fuzziness in elasticsearch (2.x)  the rewrite is [top_terms_blended_freqs_N](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-term-rewrite.html) . The score is computed using tf/idf where idf used is the same calculated using the term with the max frequency.
In short edit distance doesn't play a part in the scoring.
You could achieve what you need by constructing a query using [dis_max](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html) and [should](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to achieve the above results

Example:

```
 "query": {
      "bool": {
         "disable_coord": true,
         "should": [
            {
               "dis_max": {
                  "queries": [
                     {
                        "match": {
                           "message": {
                              "query": "triing",
                              "fuzziness": 2,
                              "fuzzy_rewrite": "constant_score",
                              "type": "phrase", 
                              "boost": 1
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match": {
                           "message": {
                              "query": "triing",
                              "fuzziness": 1,
                              "fuzzy_rewrite": "constant_score",
                              "type": "phrase", 
                              "boost": 2
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                   "message": "tiring"
                }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```